# proxy traffic coming from outside server

Tags: proxy

First of all: I don't know if this comunity is the right one for this question. If it's not I'm sorry in advance.

I'm learning about proxies right now and from what I understand I can route my traffic to a certain server and that server will take care of doing my "GET" request (if it's a webpage). My question here is the other way around: **How do you route traffic coming from an outside server?**

Lets say I have a RAT running on my computer. The server (the infected machine) is going to send the packets to my home computer. What if I want it to send it to a proxy first and then to me?

From my perspective you can rent a server and configure that server to redirect all the traffic to you but wouldn't that server be directly connected to you?

I'm asking this question because I would like to know how can criminals commit such crimes and not get caught with it. I don't know if the TOR network is involved in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do you route traffic coming from an outside server?

As far as HTTP goes, the Client initiates the connections. So your computer will first connect to this proxy and then the proxy will send that request to the Web Server. This also means that the Web Server will respond back to the Proxy and the proxy will then forward that response back to your computer.

But if you want to Route all of your traffic through a particular device, then you are looking at a Router/Firewall at that point and not just a Proxy.

> The server (the infected machine) is going to send the packets to my home computer. What if I want it to send it to a proxy first and then to me?

If you are worried about Viruses and Malware an Anti virus/ firewall will do. some even come with a builtin Proxy. here is [one](https://wiki.contribs.org/Main_Page) such opensource product.

> you can rent a server and configure that server to redirect all the traffic to you but wouldn't that server be directly connected to you?

Yes and No

Yes - because your computer is establishing a TCP Connection with this Server(proxy).

No - Because there are Proxy Service Providers out there, who may host their server(proxy) outside the jurisdiction specific to you.

In many cases, the traffic can be traced back to you. Also TOR doesn't protect you from an infected Web Server.